# How should I mount docker volumes in mlflow project?

Tags: docker, mlflow

I use `mlflow` in a docker environment as described in this [example](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/tree/master/examples/docker) and I start my runs with `mlflow run .`.

I get output like this

```sh
2019/07/17 16:08:16 INFO mlflow.projects: === Building docker image mlflow-myproject-ab8e0e4 ===
2019/07/17 16:08:18 INFO mlflow.projects: === Created directory /var/folders/93/xt2vz36s7jd1fh9bkhkk9sgc0000gn/T/tmp1lxyqqw9 for downloading remote URIs passed to arguments of type 'path' ===
2019/07/17 16:08:18 INFO mlflow.projects: === Running command 'docker run 
--rm -v /Users/foo/bar/mlruns:/mlflow/tmp/mlruns -e 
MLFLOW_RUN_ID=ef21de61d8a6436b97b643e5cee64ae1 -e MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=file:///mlflow/tmp/mlruns -e MLFLOW_EXPERIMENT_ID=0 mlflow-myproject-ab8e0e4 python train.py' in run with ID 'ef21de61d8a6436b97b643e5cee64ae1' ===
```

I would like to mount a docker volume named `my_docker_volume` to the container
 at 
the path `/data`. So instead of the `docker run` shown above, I would like to
 use

```sh
docker run --rm --mount source=my_docker_volume,target=/data -v /Users/foo/bar/mlruns:/mlflow/tmp/mlruns -e MLFLOW_RUN_ID=ef21de61d8a6436b97b643e5cee64ae1 -e MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=file:///mlflow/tmp/mlruns -e MLFLOW_EXPERIMENT_ID=0 mlflow-myproject-ab8e0e4 python train.py
```

I see that I could in principle run it once without mounted volume and then 
copy the `docker run ...` and add `--mount source=my_volume,target=/data` but
 I'd rather use something like

```sh
mlflow run --mount source=my_docker_volume,target=/data .
```

but this obviously doesn't work because --mount is not a parameter for 
`mlflow run`.
What's the recommened way of mounting a docker volume then?

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue has been brought up on the mlflow issue tracker, see "[Access large data from within a Docker environment](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/1441)". An excerpt from it says:

> However, MLFlow Docker environments currently only have access to data baked into the repository or image or must download a large dataset for each run.
>
> ...
>
> A potential solution is to enable the user to **mount a volume** (e.g. local directory containing the data) **into the Docker container**.

Looks like this is feature others would benefit from too. Best course of action here would be to contribute support for mounts, or keep track of the issue until someone else implements it.

Why do you need to mount `/data` folder in the first place? There's another issue, a [PR](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/pull/1544) containing a fix related to storing artifacts in a custom location on host machine, could it be something you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the links. Indeed [#1441](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/1441) is basically the same as my question. I'm looking forward to seeing the progress there.

Comment: @simweb it would make sense to post your workaround as a response to your own question for others to be able to find & learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Finally, to avoid the above problem and facilitate volume mounting, I now run my experiments using three interacting docker containers. One that runs the machine learning code, one that runs an `mlflow` server and one that runs a `postgresql` server. I closely followed this [walk-through article](https://towardsdatascience.com/containerize-your-whole-data-science-environment-or-anything-you-want-with-docker-compose-e962b8ce8ce5) to set things up. It works nicely and `docker-compose` makes volume mounting easy. Metrics, parameters and meta data are stored in a database that is mounted to a local persistent volume. Artifacts are logged in the directory `/mlflow` or if you prefer in a docker volume.

### Note: There's a typo in the cited walk-through article

In `docker-compose.yml` it shouldn't be

```
volumes:
  - ./postgres-store:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

which would bind a local folder named `postgres-store`.
Instead, to mount the docker volume `postgres_store`, you should use

```
volumes:
  - postgres-store:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: Could you describe how you call `mlflow run` using `docker-compose.yml` in the walk through?

Comment: @user666 I don't call `mlflow run` anymore. For my purposes, `mlflow run` was just needed to basically do `docker run` with correct propagation of the environment variables. Now the environment variables are set in the `docker-compose.yml` and instead of calling `docker run` I use `docker-compose up`.